# Adaptive size class solution for ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, size-classes

I want different label width for ipad and iphone.
For ipad width = 360 and for iphone width = 120.
How to achieve this in storyboard using adaptive size classes?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [About Designing for Multiple Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)

Comment: Do you want to change font size or actual width of label?

Comment: @devgr: width of label

Answer (score 2):

First enable `size classses`

Start applying `constraints` in **wAny hAny**.

Change `size class` to **wRegular hRegular**. This class is for iPAD's. Edit width `constraint` and change it to new value.

See the `GIF`:

[image]

When we edit constraint. A new constraint is added for that size class.

[image]

Try this and let me know if there is still any issue.

Comment: i did exactly what you suggested for ipad and for iphone i choose compact width , regular height and given some other constant value. but what happens, when my text of label get change continuously , width of label get change between 120 and 360. not getting what is exactly problem is.

Comment: Show your constraint on label. To see what exactly is happening in your case.

Comment: Please find the attached screenshots of constraints i applied.The problem is that, label is shifting between this two width.